# HTTP POST with LibCurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

Sending POST request using libcurl C++. I have tried almost all combination except the right one which I could not figure out.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  /*Not Recommended to use but since certificates are not available this is a workaround added*/
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);  /*Not Recommended to use but since certificates are not available this is a workaround added*/

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, TRUE);  //CURLOPT_POST does not work as well
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, sJson);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, bytesCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, bytesCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, &headBuffer);
```

`sJson` is a `std::string` which has the body that is created by `pb2json`.

I cannot figure out why the body is not sent ?
Is there some API i am missing if libcurl, any lead is appreciated !

Comment: body or header?

Comment: Body is not sent as the server says `Received login request with no body`

Comment: HTTPPOST sends a multipart message. You want CURLOPT_POST instead.

Comment: Even  `CURLOPT_POST` does not work

Comment: Looks like you have written custom headers too. I use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to set custom headers: curl_slist *header_list = ::curl_slist_append(nullptr, header.data()); ::curl_easy_setopt(m_curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header_list);

Comment: I haven't used custom headers @Asesh

Comment: @Simple this doesn't work `CURLOPT_POST`

Comment: Are you using `sJson` or `sJson.c_str()` as the argument to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer using custom request here `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` below is the code snippet that works fine!
When you use custom requests nothing implies and you have to explicitly define the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`

Use a list here, for brevity I have used the minimal code here.

Also when you pass `sJson` pass it as a `c type string` using `c_str()` and remember to use +1 while passing the content length (which I somehow missed initially) as in C, strings are just `char` arrays which, by convention, end with a `NULL` byte.

```
struct curl_slist* slist = NULL;
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, sJson.c_str()); /* data goes here */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, sJson.length() + 1); /* data goes here */
```

**EDIT:** Use of `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");` might create problems in redirection, use it according to your use case.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST")` though, as that will cause headaches if you later want this to follow redirects etc, and it doesn't add anything in the first case. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` implies POST.